# Connect, read, write to a device using TCP/IP in C

Tags: c, ubuntu, tcp

Good day, I just want to ask some help about connecting to a device using TCP/IP and how to properly `read()` and `write()` command to it.

Any sample codes or references would be a very big help. I don't have any idea in this particular matter but I have some knowledge in C programming and serial ports.

By the way, I'm currently using ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: We don't write code or do your research for you. What have you tried?

Comment: @Arc676 I'm not asking you to write codes. I'm just asking for links to does who have knowledge about it.

Comment: Flagging questions on SO: Flag > Close > Off topic > Questions asking for [an off-site resource]. I believe this include tutorials. @Community, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Arc676 you are not wrong and I have applied the appropriate close vote.  Also downvote, since Googling the title gives: 'About 1,050,000 results'.

Comment: Your profile says you're from the Philippines and with some changes in spelling from what you wrote "ung goy kau" > "unggoy ka" and Google Translate detects this as Filipino and translates it to "monkey". How am I meant to interpret this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what you mean by device (any device located in /dev?), but here is a tutorial on c sockets using write and read:
https://vcansimplify.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/c-socket-tutorial-echo-server/
 If you would like to gain access to a device in /dev then you just need to open it like a file and also treat it like a file (read / write from it like you would from a file).

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad someone understands my problem. I only have 1 day left to create a program and I cannot just browse and test 1,050,000 as Martin James said and realize in the end that the tutorial is deprecated or won't work. that's why I'm asking for help to those programmers that has an experienced in this particular subject. I know @Arc676 will never understand cause he's  a genius.